# Efficient ways to pass a large amount of inputs in unittest

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I am currently writing a little Python adaptation of Rummy 500 to (re)familiarize myself with the language and unittest.

I have most of my application written and running, and now it is time to test the actual game flow.

I believe my final unittest will actually simulate a given game from start to finish and confirm that the state matches what is expected during / after the game resolves.

My plan is to use mock to pass a long series of inputs to the game in order to non-interactively test that the game works interactively. I believe I can just do something like the answer suggested here: [Mock user input()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30039503/mock-user-input) but with a very long array for lines like

`@mock.patch('builtins.input', side_effect=['11', '13', 'Bob'])`

I am sure that this will work, but I can see it becoming an unwieldy mess as the input list gets longer.

Is there a better way to accomplish this same goal? My naive thought is to have a series of unit test suites that build on each other so I can just add to an array of inputs as I test each stage of the game, one after another.

E.g.

```
inputs_first_turn = ['Player 1', 'F', 1, 2, 1, 5, 'Player 2', 'M', 1, 3, 2, 5]
@mock.patch('builtins.input', side_effect=inputs_first_turn)
def test_first_turn(self, input):
    game = Game()
    # tests on game state go here

inputs_second_turn = inputs_first_turn + [3, 1, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 2, 4, 5]
@mock.patch('builtins.input', side_effect=inputs_second_turn)
def test_second_turn(self, input):
    game = Game()
    #tests on game state go here
```

repeat ad nauseum until I finish the game.

I believe this would work and would be both readable (as can be, at least) and maintainable, but I want to think there's an easier way. I am not concerned with the flow within the tests, I can muddle through that myself, but if there is a better way to do this, I would love to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `test_second_turn()` also interprets `inputs_first_turn`, why is `test_first_turn()` necessary? You're essentially testing the same inputs twice. I'd just have a single test method, where you cycle through the whole input, turn by turn. If the method becomes too large, extract subroutines that test the existing `Game` instance without creating a new one.

For mocking the whole input at once, you could put it in a multiline string literal or a separate file like `test_input.txt`, and then mock `input()` by replacing it with something like this:

```py
input_file = open('test_input.txt', 'r')
# On each call returns the next line of input from file
input = lambda: next(input_file)
```

I'm not familiar with mocking input in Python specifically, you'll probably need to use some decorator instead of `input =`. But you get the idea, put all inputs in one file/string, and mock `input` with that.

### Architecture

This is out of the scope of your question, but ideally, you shouldn't have to mock `input()` to test the game state. Instead, I usually do something like this:

```py
class GameEngine:
    def process_input(input: str):
        # game logic here
```

And test this class by providing input strings directly.

`Game` then becomes just a thin IO wrapper that does something like this:

```py
class Game:
    def run(self):
        engine = GameEngine()
        while not engine.has_finished:
            engine.process_input(input())
            print(engine.get_output())
```

Comment: Using a file makes sense. I will do that for the time being. For your beyond scope section, I believe you that it is better, but aside from not mocking inputs, what is the purpose of creating a wrapper versus just implementing the engine in Game? If I called process_input I would have to calculate what that input is supposed to be telling the game to do, depending on current game state. Is that correct? E.g I would need to calculate what menu was last displayed and for who for each input. That feels like a lot of added complexity, so what is the gain? I would love an external resource to read.

Comment: Don't you already have a similar system somewhere inside of `Game`? I mean the loop where you wait for the next portion of input and then mutate state based on that

Comment: Yeah. I have, for example, `create_player(self): self.players[0] = input("enter player name")` (more than that but you get the idea), which is called within `Game.setup_game()` which is called by `Game.run()` after New Game is selected from the first menu. I am unsure what I gain from pulling all of that out and creating process_input to handle the branching instead, beyond not having to mock inputs. I guess it is cleaner? I am currently looking at doing it the way you've suggested, so I'm sure it will make sense once I actually work with it. Now I'm stuck on the "how", however.

Comment: `process_input()` in my example isn't supposed to handle stuff like player names. It's supposed to handle the in-game commands. I'd get the player names somewhrere up the stack: `engine.players[0] = input("enter player name")`, inside of something like `GameIO.setup_game()` (`GameIO` owns a `GameEngine` instance and provides input to it). Menus should be part of `GameIO` instead of `GameEngine`, and call specialized `GameEngine` methods like `.set_player_name()` (not a single `process_input()` that encapsulates everything)

Comment: That makes more sense. I will look at this further and see what I can come up with. Thank you for your answer and additional help.

Comment: If you completely move input and menus out of the engine, you'll even be able to reuse it with a GUI

Comment: In games, I've only done toy CLIs like yours (not even curses), so I can't point you at resources with better explanation of this principle. For me, it's just separation of logic and IO, seems natural in any project. I remember reading something about this idea in [The Art Of Unix Programming](http://www.catb.org/esr/writings/taoup/html/)

Comment: Yeah. I am actually doing it now and it makes sense to me. Thank you for the correction. I am just screwing up as I go and learning from the headaches, so thanks for making my future 'oh god why' smaller. The unit testing is easier to figure out this way, too.

Comment: Nice to see my offtopic advice actually work out as a solution to XY problem. Consider marking as accepted then

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use the `ddt` module which lets you parametrize `unittest` and call the same test repeatedly with different data.

This example shows how to create a generator which returns a bigger slice of the full data each time. Just modify `gamedata` to yield your turns:

```
import unittest
from ddt import ddt, idata

def gamedata():
    fullgame = [[0,1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
    for i in range(1, len(fullgame)+1):
        yield fullgame[:i]

@ddt
class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    
    @idata(gamedata())
    def test_foo(self, data):
        print('DATA:', data)
        # Replace with real tests
        assert True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

```
DATA: [[0, 1]]
.DATA: [[0, 1], [2, 3]]
.DATA: [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]]
.DATA: [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5], [6, 7]]
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 4 tests in 0.000s

OK
```