# Create automated tests for interactive shell based on Python's cmd module

Tags: python, python-3.x, tdd, pytest, python-cmd

I am building an interactive shell using Python 3 and the cmd module.  I have already written simple unit tests using py.test to test the individual functions, such as the do_* functions.  I'd like to create more comprehensive tests that actually interact with the shell itself by simulating a user's input.  For example, how could I test the following simulated session:

```
bash$ console-app.py
md:> show options
  Available Options:
  ------------------
  HOST      The IP address or hostname of the machine to interact with
  PORT      The TCP port number of the server on the HOST
md:> set HOST localhost
  HOST => 'localhost'
md:> set PORT 2222
  PORT => '2222'
md:>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `mock` `input` or input stream passed to cmd to inject user input but I find more simple and flexible test  it by `onecmd()` `Cmd` API method and trust how `Cmd` read input. In this way you cannot care how `Cmd` do the dirty work and test directly by users command: I use `cmd` both by console and socket and this I cannot care where the stream come from.

Moreover I use `onecmd()` to test even `do_*` (and occasionally `help_*`) methods and make my test less coupled to the code.

Follow a simple example of how I use it. `create()` and `_last_write()` are helper methods to build a `MyCLI` instance and take the last output lines respectively.

```
from mymodule import MyCLI
from unittest.mock import create_autospec

class TestMyCLI(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.mock_stdin = create_autospec(sys.stdin)
        self.mock_stdout = create_autospec(sys.stdout)

    def create(self, server=None):
        return MyCLI(stdin=self.mock_stdin, stdout=self.mock_stdout)

    def _last_write(self, nr=None):
        """:return: last `n` output lines"""
        if nr is None:
            return self.mock_stdout.write.call_args[0][0]
        return "".join(map(lambda c: c[0][0], self.mock_stdout.write.call_args_list[-nr:]))

    def test_active(self):
        """Tesing `active` command"""
        cli = self.create()
        self.assertFalse(cli.onecmd("active"))
        self.assertTrue(self.mock_stdout.flush.called)
        self.assertEqual("Autogain active=False\n", self._last_write())
        self.mock_stdout.reset_mock()
        self.assertFalse(cli.onecmd("active TRue"))
        self.assertTrue(self.mock_stdout.flush.called)
        self.assertEqual("Autogain active=True\n", self._last_write())
        self.assertFalse(cli.onecmd("active 0"))
        self.assertTrue(self.mock_stdout.flush.called)
        self.assertEqual("Autogain active=False\n", self._last_write())

    def test_exit(self):
        """exit command"""
        cli = self.create()
        self.assertTrue(cli.onecmd("exit"))
        self.assertEqual("Goodbay\n", self._last_write())
```

Take care that `onecmd()` return `True` if your cli should terminate, `False` otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

Use python [mock](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html) library to simulate user input. Here you will find similar problems with examples [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21046717/python-mocking-raw-input-in-unittests), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2617057/supply-inputs-to-python-unit-tests).