# How to write unit tests for Functions requiring input and as a result, calling other functions?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing

Suppose I have this code. Really unsure how to Unit test this seeing as it is a void method, requires user input, and the valid answer for one of the cases is to just call another method. Like how do I test this?

````
def start():
    user_Response = input(
        '\n' "○ Press 1 to Enter the Main Menu" '\n'
        "○ Press 2 or type 'exit' to Exit \n ")

    if user_Response == str(1):
        mainMenu()

    elif user_Response == str(2) or user_Response.lower() == "exit":
        print(
            'Thank you, good bye.
        exit()

    else:
        "Please enter a valid response."
        start() ```
````

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38861365/1898256) might be useful for mocking stdin and stdout.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite the function. Instead of calling `input`, I would pass a file-like object as an argument which you can iterate over. The caller can be responsible for passing `sys.stdin` or some other file-like object (such as an instance of `io.StringIO`) for ease of testing.

I would also ditch recursion in favor of a simple loop.

```
def start(input_stream):
    while True:
        print("...")
        user_response = input_stream.readline().rstrip('\n')

        if user_response == "1":
            return mainMenu()

        elif user_response == "2" or user_response.lower() == "exit":
            print('Thank you, good bye.')
            exit()

        else:
            print("Please enter a valid response.")
```

A sample test:

```
def test_loop():
    try:
        start(io.StringIO("exit"))
    except SystemExit:
        pass
    else:
        assert False, "start did not exit"
```